# How to do a 3-part IF statement in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, with-statement

```
'8
If Not IsEmpty(Range("A7")) And Range("C7") = "\" Then
    Range("W7") = "\"
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("A7")) And Range("C7") <> "\" Then
    Range("W7") = "\L"
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("A7")) Then
    Range("W7") = ""
End If

With Sheets("DL Data")
    .Range("W7:W" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "\L"
End With
```

I cannot seem to figure out the WITH part, or maybe I am off on the IF statement all together. What I am trying to do here is this:

IF A7 is not empty AND it equals "\" THEN W7 equals "\", also
IF A7 is not empty AND it does not equal "\" THEN W7 equals "\L", also
IF A7 is empty THEN W7 equals blank

Then I would like it to do this to search through the Column and give me the appropriate answer, inserting blanks where necessary, inserting "\" where necessary and inserting "\L" where necessary.

Hope I am making myself clear here, thanks for all of the help in advance!

Regards,

Yazz

Comment: your first bit of logic is redundant.  if A7="\", then obviously, it can't be empty

Comment: Code of your first if clause says something different then your explanation.  `A7 <> "" and A7 = "\"` OR `A7 <> "" and C7 = "\"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `With` is simply an abbreviation.

For example

```
With Sheets("DL Data")
    .Range("W7:W" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "\L"
End With
```

Is equivalent to

```
Sheets("DL Data").Range("W7:W" & Sheets("DL Data").Cells(Sheets("DL Data").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "\L"
```

You need a loop in order to apply this condition to all of the rows, for example:

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 7 To Sheets("DL Data").Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) And Range("C" & i) = "\" Then
    Range("W" & i) = "\"
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) And Range("C" & i) <> "\" Then
    Range("W" & i) = "\L"
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then
    Range("W" & i) = ""
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Uri Goren...when I grow up, I want to be just like you. It worked like a charm. I am going to study this and understand the logic. I think I need to brush up on my LOOP function, since that seems to be the answer to MOST of my VBA questions. Thank you very much for this. Huge help!

Comment: Hey Uri, if I have only one line it needs to search for instead of 'more than one' in that column, it gives me an error, i am guessing since the xlDown function doesnt see any further row below that first entry...is there a way to have it not do that even if there is only one entry within the first row?

Comment: Run the `For` loop from `7` To `IIf(Sheets("DL Data").Range("A8")="",7,Sheets("DL Data").Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row)`

Comment: what the...i am just in awe dude...i thought the "IIF" was a typo so I copied it without it and it didnt work and when i did and now it works...i just...damn, if you have any recommendations on where to study up on Loop, For, statements, i'd love to know! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it through the whole column, you need to nest the same If-block into a loop:

```
With Sheets("DL Data")
For j = 7 To .Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
    If .Range("A" & j) <> "" And .Range("C" & j) = "\" Then
        .Range("W" & j) = "\"
    ElseIf .Range("A" & j) <> "" And .Range("C" & j) <> "\" Then
        .Range("W" & j) = "\L"
    ElseIf .Range("A" & j) = "" Then
        .Range("W" & j) = ""
    End If
Next j
End With
```

**WARNING** I have followed your current implementation; however, if your column "A" might have some empty cells in between (which would explain the presence of a `ElseIf .Range("A" & j) = ""`), pay attention to the fact that the counter `.Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row` would stop at the first empty cell. You might want to index your counter into an always filled-up column (such as a record-ID of your data set).

Comment: What I have for other criteria are only IF A7 <> "" THEN C7 = "whatever" ElseIF A7 = "" THEN C7 = ""...I have the criteria working the way I wanted it to but the problem lies within the WITH statement. I cannot get it to scan the entire column and if A is empty, then leave everything empty too, no blanks in between, so if you had 100 entries, you would have 100 filled entries and then blanks all AFTER the initial 100 it does not skip in between

Answer (score 0):

This update to your code will update the `W` column according to your formula. I optimized the `If` statements a bit to make them less redundant.

Additionally, I have included a couple of `With` blocks for illustration purposes.

```
With Sheets("DL Data")
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 7 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        With .Range("A" & row)
            ' IF A is empty THEN W equals blank
            If .Value = "" Then
                Range("W" & row).Value = ""

            ' IF A is not empty AND it equals "\" THEN W equals "\"
            If .Value = "\" Then
                Range("W" & row).Value = "\"

            ' IF A is not empty AND it does not equal "\" THEN W equals "\L"
            ' A is not empty (first condition checked above).
            ElseIf .Value <> "\"
                Range("W" & row).Value = "\L"

            End If
        End With

    Next
End With
```